# Nesting <p> and <img>, like '<p><img src=''></p>'

Tags: html, css

as mentioned in the title, Nesting `<p>` and `<img>`.

On the right of `<img>`, I would like to output some text by coding below

```
<p><img src="images/sp_luffy.png" alt="タルトの写真”>This is ruffy</p>
```

but Actually, This isn't working well, only image can be seen in the browser(chrome)

if anyone know something about it and need more information, Please let me know.

whole code in this file.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>KUJIRA Cafeについて| KUJIRA Cafe</title>
</head>
    <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
    <!-- ヘッダー -->
        <header class="header">
                <h1 class="logo"><a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="KUJIRA Cafe" ></a></h1>
                <nav class="nav">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="index.html">ホーム</a></li>
                            <li><a href="about.html">店舗案内</a></li>
                            <li><a href="access.html">アクセス</a></li>
                            <li><a href="menu.htmlメニュー"></a></li>
                            <li><a href="contact.html">お問い合わせ</a></li>

                        </ul>
                </nav>
        </header>
        <!-- ヘッダー ここまで -->
        <!-- メイン -->        
    <main>
        <p><img src="images/sp_luffy.png" alt="タルトの写真”>This is ruffy</p>

        <h2>手作りタルトと香り高い珈琲で、寛ぎのカフェタイムを</h2>
    </main>
    <!-- メインここまで -->
    <!-- フッター -->
        <footer class="footer">
            <p>&copy;Copyright KUJIRA Cafe. All right reserved. Ako</p>
        </footer>
    <!-- フッターここまで -->
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `<img />` HTML element is not using the correct double-quote character for the `alt=""` attribute. Instead it's using a curly-double-quote (instead of a straight-double-quote) and the browser interprets the curly-double-quote (and the `>` and text after it) as part of the `alt` attribute value.

Change this:

```
<p><img src="images/sp_luffy.png" alt="タルトの写真”>This is ruffy</p>

                                                  ^ Here is the problem
```

to this:

```
<p><img src="images/sp_luffy.png" alt="タルトの写真">This is ruffy</p>

                                                  ^ Use " instead of ”
```

HTML attribute values can only be delimited with `'` or `"` (quotes are also optional if the value does not contain any spaces, puncutation or other special characters).

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt comment.
now, it is working well.